# Can't fully squash commits

Tags: git, git-squash

[image]

The commit `Paises ISO 3166-1` all modify the same files and leave them in the same state.

Is there any way to make it so there's only 1 commit `Paises ISO 3166-1` on the blue line right before the branches?

I've tried `git rebase -i c5d892b4` but the current situation is the result.

In this repo `custom` is the base code for all branches with each branch possibly having their own specific changes. So I'd like for someone else to be able to tell that the branches branch off of `custom` which isn't that clear right now.

How I want to have it is how I had it before I messed up with the squashing.

#### Edit:

Basically commits:

- 0a691a8c
- cc4861a3
- 452b4608
- 846721da

should not exist.

Comment: All I had to do was `git rebase custom` on each branch. -_-

Comment: Rebasing each branch onto `custom` worked because each of the commits with that name contained the same changes, and after the rebase they became empty commits which fell out.